# Angular2 - Multiple service calls in OnInit method of component

Tags: node.js, rest, angular

How can I make two service calls in the OnInit() method of the component ?

```
export class ApartmentComponent implements OnInit {
    public apartments: Object[];
    public temp: Object[];

    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService) {
    this.apartmentService = apartmentService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.apartmentService.getApartments().subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);

    this.apartmentService.getStats().subscribe(res => this.temp = res);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.temp));
    }
}
```

In service.ts

```
getApartments() {
    return this.http.get('./api/businessunits/butype').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getStats(){ 
    console.log('Request reached');
    return this.http.get('./api/apartments/getstats').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

in server.ts (ExpressJS)

```
router.route('/api/businessunits/butype')             
.get(function(req, res) {
    BusinessUnit.find({unitID: {$exists: true}, UnitType: {$exists:  true}},'unitID UnitType',{sort:{unitID: 1}},function(err, businessunits) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(businessunits);
     });
});

router.route('/api/apartments/getstats')             
.get(function(req, res) {
    //Apartment.aggregate([{$match:{_id: "aptType"}},{$group:{_id:{aptType:"$aptType"},count:{$sum:1}}}],function(err, apartments) {
      Apartment.find('aptType',function(err, apartments) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(apartments);
     });
});
```

The getApartments() works fine individually when I comment out getStats() method call.

I am getting the following error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\node_modules\express
```

Comment: I don't think the error message is related to the code you posted. What call does result in that error `getApartments()` or `getStats()`. Can you please post the code of these methods?

Comment: Added the service ts

Comment: Seems the error is caused by the server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to observables is an async operation, that means this just schedules a tasks to be done later.

When `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.temp)` is executed, the call to the server in `getStats()` (if it actually makes one - I just assume it does) wasn't even sent, and therefor definitely no response received yet.

It is also not clear from the code in your question whether the request for `getApartments()` or `getStats()` is sent first.

To preserve a specific order in async operations, you need to chain them properly so that the next is executed when the former is completed.

If you just want to print the result of `getStats()` this can be done like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apartmentService.getApartments().subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);

  this.apartmentService.getStats().subscribe(res => {
    this.temp = res;
    JSON.stringify(this.temp)
  });
}
```

alternatives are

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apartmentService.getApartments().subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);

  this.apartmentService.getStats()
  .map(res => this.temp = res);
  .subscribe(temp => console.log(JSON.stringify(this.temp));
  });
}
```

or

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apartmentService.getApartments().subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);

  this.apartmentService.getStats()
  .map(res => this.temp = res);
  .toPromise().then(temp => console.log(JSON.stringify(this.temp));
  });
}
```

If you want to chain 2 subscribes

```
this.apartmentService.getApartments().subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);
this.apartmentService.getStats().subscribe(res => this.temp = res);
```

there are lots of possiblilities like `flatMap()` depending on your requirements. You might want that they are sent one after the other is completed, or send both as soon as possible but then wait for both to complete. There are different ways to handle errors, ...

For more details see http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html